# Silverlight: Changing the Background-Brush on MouseOver

Tags: silverlight, animation

in my Silverlight-Application, I want to change the Background-Brush of my button on mouse-over. I made a style for my button and changed the MouseOver-VisualState:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
    <Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Background>{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}</Background>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

which doesn't work because 'The name "Background" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".' Any idea, how I can set the Background-Brush to Border-Brush on mouse-over without doing it with code behind and the appropriate events?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work, because I can't use Binding in the VisualStateManager, as explained here: [Using TemplateBinding in ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440292/using-templatebinding-in-objectanimationusingkeyframes)

Answer (score 1):

`Background` is a property of `Control` not `UIElement` which is why it isn't working.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

You'll need to use the following:

```
... Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background)" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, it still tells me that 'The name "Background" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".' (The bugging line is the <Background>{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}</Background> line, btw.) If I explicitly type <Control.Background>{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}</Control.Background> it tells me, that nested properties are not supported

Comment: This whole thing doesn't work because I can't use Binding in the VisualStateManager.